# Hide a button if table blank and display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to hide a button and display text if no results are returned in my table.

The code below if what I have for my table:

```
<table class="stripped" id="table">
<tr>
    <th>DB ID</th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Environment", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EnviroSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Product", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ProductSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Test Type", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TestTypeSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Scenario", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ScenarioSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Times Run", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TimesRunSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Failed Count", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FailedCountSortParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Last 'Passed' Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastPassedDateParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Last 'Failed' Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastFailedDateParam })
    </th>
    <th>
        Actions
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Environment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TestType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Scenario)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimesRun)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FailedCount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastPassedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastFailedDate)
        </td>
        <td class="Link">
            @if (item.LastFailedDate != null)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(item.LastFailedDate).Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                   @Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the code below displays the code for my export button:

```
<div class="RightAlign">
    <button class="butstyle" id="Export" onclick="Export_Click" title="Click to export the results above as a CSV file.">
        Export To Excel <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

As I said, I want the button to be hidden if no results are found and the following displayed:

```
<p id="NRF" class="NRF">No Test Runs Found.</p>
```

How can I do this or what's the best way to as I cant seem to get my head around it.  I am using HTML5 & MVC5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@if(Model.Count>0)
{

<div class="RightAlign">
    <button class="butstyle" id="Export" onclick="Export_Click" title="Click to export the results above as a CSV file.">
        Export To Excel <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
    </button>
</div>
}

else
{
<p id="NRF" class="NRF">No Test Runs Found.</p>
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked.  I had to change the 'Model.Count' though so it read: @if(Model.Count() > 0).  Once  did this it worked perfect.